# Script error in require.js backbone project

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am a new developer with backbone and require.js.

This is the structure of my project :

[image]

And this my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="app/script/libs/require.js" data-main="app/script/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is main.js :

```
require.config({
   paths: {
     jquery: 'app/script/libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.1',
     underscore: 'app/script/libs/underscore/underscore',
     backbone: 'app/script/libs/backbone/backbone'
   },
   shim: {
     backbone: ['jquery', 'underscore']
   }
 });

 require(['app'], function(App){
     App.initialize();
 });
```

And then when I browse in the browser, I got this error in the console of firefox :

```
Error: Script error http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
[Break On This Error]   

...irejs.org/docs/errors.html#"+b);c.requireType=b;c.requireModules=i;d&&(c.origina...
```

Anyone can tell me, how this error come please? Thanks.

Comment: Try to use the development version of require (not minified). And can you post the content of your main.js file?

Comment: @Tallmaris : I post it ready dear.

Answer (score 1):

Your require.config contains folders which dont exist. There are no folders such as backbone, jquery, underscore under the app/libs

Change your require.config to the following

```
require.config({
   paths: {
     jquery: 'app/script/libs/jquery-1.7.1',
     underscore: 'app/script/libs/underscore',
     backbone: 'app/script/libs/backbone'
   },
   shim: {
     backbone: ['jquery', 'underscore']
   }
 });

 require(['app'], function(App){
     App.initialize();
 });
```